# Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser> ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 Identity.  I've overridden IdentityUser because I need to add some additional properties on the user.

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<PortalUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<PortalUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

PortalUser class

```
public class PortalUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public DateTime? LastLoginDateUtc { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public DateTime? RegistrationDateUtc { get; set; }
}
```

That's all working fine.  I can add a user via.

```
_userManager.CreateAsync(user)
```

However, when I call AddToRolesAsync to add a role to a user, I'm getting an exception.  Any ideas why?

```
_userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, new List<string> { roleName });

{System.NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetUserRoleStore()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.AddToRolesAsync(TUser user, IEnumerable`1 roles)}
```

Comment: *I've overridden IdentityUser* What do you mean by this? You need to show us your code, the question is not answerable as it stands.

Comment: Fair enough. I've edited my question.

Comment: What does `ApplicationDbContext` inherit from?

Comment: IdentityDbContext<PortalUser>

Answer (score 110, accepted):

In Startup.cs, I was missing AddRoles so

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<PortalUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

should be

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<PortalUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Note: The order is critical.  `AddRoles` must come before `AddEntityFrameworkStores`

Comment: You should accept this answer even if you have answered your question yourself.

Answer (score 7):

For there are not any answers about the solution in **asp.net Core 2.2**, I would like to share the same error I meet in **asp.net Core 2.2**

First, here is another solution for the same error in **asp.net core 2.1**
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/8683

And thanks to the author's idea, I meet the problem when I follow the official guidance in **asp.net core 2.2** (the url is in here : [MicrosoftDocs For asp.net core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2)). When I finish the step he says and try to run the project, it throws a exception **"Store does not implement IUserRoleStore"**

and the problem is : actually, this is the sample for asp.net core 2.1 (And I strongly doubt that why the Microsoft will provide users a docs with not any sample codes, which can't make sense probably)

And you will find that, in **Areas/Identity/Data/IdentityHostingStartup.cs IdentityHostingStartup::Configure method** you have the following codes :

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

which is same as the code you should add in **/Program.cs ConfigureService** as the step : **Add Role services to Identity** in docs mentioned :

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

**so if you meet the same problem in asp.net core 2.2, an alternative solution is :**

1. Following the docs in asp.net 2.2
2. When you meet this Chapter : **Add Role services to Identity** , just ignore the official docs and do it :

replace the row

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

with

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

in **Areas/Identity/Data/IdentityHostingStartup.cs IdentityHostingStartup::Configure** method, but not add it in program.cs (the file can't be deleted in asp.net core 2.2)

The project I use Asp.net Identity will be updated later in my repos : [UWPHelper](https://github.com/ZyuHoiMing/UwpHelper) , Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the author already fixed his issue ,but I'll add this for anyone else that did all the steps in the above answer and still has this error.

From
[Aspnet github](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8683)

You must delete autogenerated IdentityHostingStartup.Configure method in **Areas/Identity/IdentityHostingStartup.cs**