# One or more errors occurred. (Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-7.0

I'm having a problem using RoleManager in .NET 7 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity (2.2.0)
Everything compiles ok but when I go to get the roles from my JWT Middleware I get an exception when calling GetRolesAsync:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Store does
> not implement IUserRoleStore.)  --->
> System.NotSupportedException: Store does not implement
> IUserRoleStore.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetUserRoleStore()    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetRolesAsync(TUser user)

*DBContext/Entity Classes*

```
 public class MyDataContext : IdentityDbContext<MyTypeOfUser, IdentityRole, string>
    {
            public MyDataContext (DbContextOptions options)
                : base(options) { }
             ...
    }

public class MyTypeOfUser: IdentityUser
{
..
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<MyTypeOfUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()        
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDataContext>();
```

*JWT - GetJWTBearer Class*

```
 var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager<MyTypeOfUser>>();
                        var user = userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Principal).Result;
                        var roles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
```

I've seen a few similar questions here - namely:
[.NET Core 7: Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74439495/net-core-7-store-does-not-implement-iuserrolestoretuser)
and
[Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser> ASP.NET Core Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522248/store-does-not-implement-iuserrolestoretuser-asp-net-core-identity)

However I've implemented all fixes I can see from their answers that I can whilst using .NET 7.  The database seems to have created the right tables...  I'm flumoxed!

Answer (score 0):

OK I had missed something.
I also had this in program.cs... added sometime earlier.

```
IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuctionDataContext>(        
        AddIdentityFrameworkCore(builder.Services)        
    );
```

Removing it seems to have resolved the issue.